# working on select but not on blur - EXTJS

Tags: extjs

I am newbie to ExtJS I have the following lines of code that is working fine on select event and now I am planning to add on blur event too.

```
autoResolve.on("select" || "blur", function (component, record, index) {
        var fieldSet = utils.getComponentFromMngr(component.id.split("~")[0]);
            if(autoResolveData.CURRSEL){ //Set previous selection property

                var xmlElem = fieldSet.DomainXML.documentElement.childNodes[1];
                    xmlElem.setAttribute("PR_DOMAINTYPE",autoResolveData.FILL_SUBTYP);
                    xmlElem.setAttribute("PR_DOMAINID", record.get("ITEMID"));
                    xmlElem.setAttribute("PR_DOMAINVALUE", record.data.TITLE);
                    fieldSet.DomainObj.push({PRDomainType:autoResolveData.FILL_SUBTYP,PRDomainID:record.get("ITEMID"),PRDomainValue:record.data.TITLE});
            }
```

it is still working fine on select event but not on blur event where am I going wrong please suggest

Comment: Where did you get `'select' || 'blur'` from ?

Answer (score 0):

`"select" || "blur"` will return `select`, as you can find out if you type the following in browser console:

```
console.log("select" || "blur");
```

Furthermore, `"blur"` event does not have `record` as the second parameter. You would have to look how to get `record` and call the function with a valid `record` parameter.

What you want to achieve is roughly the following:

```
var myFunction = function (component, record, index) {
    var fieldSet = utils.getComponentFromMngr(component.id.split("~")[0]);
    if(autoResolveData.CURRSEL){ //Set previous selection property
        var xmlElem = fieldSet.DomainXML.documentElement.childNodes[1];
        xmlElem.setAttribute("PR_DOMAINTYPE",autoResolveData.FILL_SUBTYP);
        xmlElem.setAttribute("PR_DOMAINID", record.get("ITEMID"));
        xmlElem.setAttribute("PR_DOMAINVALUE", record.data.TITLE);
        fieldSet.DomainObj.push({PRDomainType:autoResolveData.FILL_SUBTYP,PRDomainID:record.get("ITEMID"),PRDomainValue:record.data.TITLE});
    }
};
autoResolve.on({
    select:myFunction,
    blur:function(component) {
        var record = ... // your special magic here
        return myFunction(component,record);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your response. can I fire select event handler on blur event.

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't, because there are possible side effects with other event handlers. I have provided you (more or less) clean code. You would always have to calculate and provide the "selected" record during blur, there's no way around that.